# Remains state on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an application now with react.
Set the calculation function, and `sum: 0` specified by state remains at the beginning.
This is the actual operation.
https://www.useloom.com/share/43bd30dc0f0741f7b09c63a3728d2ba9

```
    import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";

    class Account extends Component {
      state = { sum: 0 };
      input = event => {
        this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
        console.log(this.state.input);
      };
      Plus = () => {
        this.setState({ sum: this.state.sum + this.state.input });
      };
      Main = () => {
        this.setState({ sum: this.state.sum - this.state.input });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <h2>口座</h2>
            <h3>
              現在:&nbsp;
              {this.state.sum}
            </h3>
            <input onChange={this.input} />
            <br />
            <button onClick={this.Plus}>収入</button>
            <button onClick={this.Main}>支出</button>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Account;
```

Please let me know the way to erase the leading zeros and why `sum: 0` is left.
Thank you.

Comment: The error is because you are adding/subtracting a `String` to a `Number` (for example `const result = 0 + '0000'`). What you can do instead is parse the `event.target.value` so that it becomes a `Number` instead: `this.setState({ input: parseInt(event.target.value) });`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are doing a string concatenation rather than a sum.

You need to get a number from your input, for example through `+` operator:

```
this.setState({ input: +(event.target.value) });
```

Then, when you want to set the state based on the previous state, you should use the `setState` method with a callback as argument, which provides you the previous state, like:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ sum: prevState.sum + prevState.input }));
```

Then when you init your state, you should specify all the state:

```
state = { sum: 0, input: 0 };
```

So your final code should look something like:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";

class Account extends Component {
  state = { sum: 0, input: 0 };
  input = event => {
    this.setState({ input: +(event.target.value) });
    console.log(this.state.input);
  };
  Plus = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ sum: prevState.sum + prevState.input }));
  };
  Main = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ sum: prevState.sum - prevState.input }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h2>口座</h2>
        <h3>
          現在:&nbsp;
          {this.state.sum}
        </h3>
        <input value={this.state.input} onChange={this.input} />
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.Plus}>収入</button>
        <button onClick={this.Main}>支出</button>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Account;
```

Comment: Thank you very carefully for explaining.
Understanding of state has deepened. @quirimmo

Answer (score 2):

Two things: your input is becoming uncontrolled, and you have to cast the value from string to number.

The first is a subtle issue that will be more helpful for more advanced app you'll made. You have to assign a `value` prop to your input, this way:

```
<input value={ this.state.input } onChange={this.input} />
```

Remeber also to assign an initial value to state.input, something like an empty string is fine.

The main problem you have is the casting of the input value to a string, you can do it with:

```
this.setState({ input: Number(event.target.value) })
```

One more thing, when you update state using value from the state itself, use the method notation instead the object one:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ sum: prevState.sum + prevState.input }))
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me the solution thought about the application.
It was very helpful.